# how do i delete correct object after mat sorting?

Tags: angular, sorting, material-design

i have delete click listener where i pass index and id from my data source, but after sorting index changes and when i click delete the item is delete from database with id but in ui different item is spliced because of index change after sorting

this is my html file

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Delete </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index;">
              <button mat-mini-fab color="warn" (click)="delete(row?.id, i + (paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize))">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
              </button>
            </td>
</ng-container>
```

this is my ts code

```
delete(id, index) {
    var flag = confirm("Do you want to delete?");
    if (flag){
      this.productsServ.delete(id, index);
    }
  }
```

this my service file code

```
delete(id, index) {
    this.http.delete('http://localhost:8000/api/product/'+id).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.snackBar.open('Deleted.', 'Dismiss', {duration: 3000});
        this.products.splice(index, 1);
        this.productsChanged.next(this.products);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: send request to server wait for returning new list value from server don't use index

Comment: Since the id is unique you can filter your products-array for the deleted Id: `this.products = this.products.filter(product => product.id != id)`

Comment: this helped me - `dataSource.filteredData.indexOf(row)` instead of using - `let i = index`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but I think the issue is with the index variable which does not update dynamically after sorting. I prefer using a different approach:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="action">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="action"><mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon></button>
              <mat-menu #action="matMenu">
                <button mat-menu-item (click)="openEditUser(row)">Edit</button>
                <button mat-menu-item (click)="onDelete(row)">Delete</button>
              </mat-menu>
            </td>
</ng-container>
```

And within typescript file,

```
onDelete(data) {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
  width: '500px',
  disableClose: false,
  autoFocus: false,
});
dialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage = "Are you sure you want to delete this user?";
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(r => {
  if(r)
    this.afs.collection('users').doc(data.uid).delete();
})
}
```

Don't get confused with the confirmdialogcomponent, it just displays a confirmation with Yes/No.